# Batch printing files stored on server from website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net website which is hosted on AWS.

From this website I need to be able to select multiple PDF files from a list stored on the AWS box and then print them.

Currently my process only allows one PDF to be printed at a time by redirecting them to the PDF filepath within the browser and then the user manually printing from there but this process will become a tedious one should they have many to print.

Anybody have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A really quick easy way in my opinion is just copy the file to printer path.
This works for both word docs and pdf's.
This assumes a couple of things however:

1.) The documents are stored some where were you can copy them from.

2.) You have the printer driver installed on your Web server.

3.) Adobe reader must be installed on the web server. (otherwise printers don't recognize PDF's sometimes.)

So what I do is Query the printers on the server via the ManagementObjectSearcher find the default printer or whatever one you want grab the printer path and then copy the file to the path.
That is it.
Code is really simple.

```
    public static class PrinterHelper
    {

    public class PrinterSettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }

        public string DeviceId { get; set; }
        public string ShareName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool Default { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the file to printer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePathAndName">Name of the file path and Name of File.</param>
    /// <param name="printerName">Name of the printer with Path. E.I. \\SFDPRINT2.raven.ravenind.net\P14401</param>
    public static void SendFileToPrinter(string filePathAndName, string printerName)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePathAndName);
        file.CopyTo(printerName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all printers that have drivers installed on the calling machine.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<PrinterSettings> GetAllPrinters()
    {
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        List<PrinterSettings> printers = new List<PrinterSettings>();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {
            PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
            foreach (PropertyData property in mo.Properties)
            {
                if (property.Name == "Name")
                    printer.Name = property.Value == null ? "" : property.Value.ToString();

                if (property.Name == "ServerName")
                    printer.ServerName = property.Value == null ? "" : property.Value.ToString();

                if (property.Name == "DeviceId")
                    printer.DeviceId = property.Value == null ? "" : property.Value.ToString();

                if (property.Name == "ShareName")
                    printer.ShareName = property.Value == null ? "" : property.Value.ToString();

                if (property.Name == "Comment")
                    printer.Comment = property.Value == null ? "" : property.Value.ToString();

                if (property.Name == "Default")
                    printer.Default = (bool)property.Value;
            }
            printers.Add(printer);
        }

        return printers;
    }      
}
```

This how to use the helper. that is it.

```
            var printer = PrinterHelper.GetAllPrinters().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Default);
            PrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(printer.Name, "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Form - Career Advancement Request.pdf");
```

Comment: I did not catch that this was AWS.  I dont know what you are bound to with that, however I will post my code shortly and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake, the how to use the helper has the arguments reversed. First pass the filename and then the printer name.